# simple motor driver wouldn't work

Tags: mosfet, motor, vibration-motor

I am using ATMega164PA as the microcontroller running at 8MHz on 3V coin battery (current battery voltage 2.5V). I am trying to turn on tiny coin vibration motor rated 3V, 90mA using ZXMN10A07FTA N-type MOSFET.

Now that the battery voltage is at 2.5V and the vibration motor wouldn't turn on. I noticed that the gate of the MOSFET is at 2.5V which is good but the drain of the mosfet is also at 2.5V (shouldn't the drain be pulled to ground when mosfet is turned on?). There are no soldering faults, the components are at the right place. I have uploaded my schematic and the pins the gate of the mosfets are connected to.

Does anyone see any fault with the design or any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [transistor datasheet](http://diodes.com/datasheets/ZXMN10A07F.pdf), The gate threshold voltage can be anywhere from 2V to 4V, and that's specified at a drain current of just 250 µA.

Basically, when the battery voltage drops that low, you don't have enough to turn the MOSFETs on — certainly not on hard enough to drive a motor.

Comment: Even when I use a regulated 3.3V supply, the motors wouldn't go. What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: You either need to pick a different transistor that has a lower threshold voltage, or you need to raise the gate voltage somehow (perhaps with some sort of charge pump).

Answer (score 1):

Use a BSS138 n-fet transistor. Vth = 1.5 volt max

Comment: It might be worth adding a bit more detail on Vth and what it means so they learn how to select FETs in the future.

Comment: This part has a high Rds(on) resistance. Even if the FET is fully on wouldn't that get warm when Id is something like 100mA? Also I need Id to be more than 300mA

Comment: @PeterJ if I feed in a higher voltage than 1.5V say 3V, that shouldn't blow the fet up right considering the max Vgs is 20V?

Comment: If you need more then the 0.22 amp continuous  that the BSS138 is specified for, you will have to located a FET with a higher current rating and low Vth. Fairchild has a series called logic FETs and have higher current versions. Your problem definition did not specify a current requirement.

Comment: @waltx, I need the mosfet to drive a vibration motor 3V, 90mA like I mentioned in my question. Althought the motor takes around 120mA start up current which is why I arrived at a figure of 300mA to keep some headroom.